# To draw a graph with only two eccentricties.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was trying to convert graphs $C_8$ and $C_9$ into graphs $A$ and $B$, by adding two extra vertices, such that both $A$ and $B$  contains **exactly two vertices** with eccentricity three and rest with eccentricity four, and $C_8$ is induced in $A$ and $C_9$ is induced in $B$. Kindly help me to get the graph (*may be by adding 3 vertices*). Any hint or suggestion will be helpful. Following is my (failed) attempt.

***Graph $A$***

[image]

***Graph $B$***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to mess around with this and get an answer, but I wasn't able to find a great procedure. I really just arrived at the conclusion that the vertices with eccentricity $3$ probably should be the newly introduced vertices. In order for this to work out any "bridge" that they create in the original $C_8$ (or $C_9$) couldn't be a "shortcut" for any vertices in the cycle. Note how both graphs are structurally similar. I bet this concept could generalize nicely for higher order cycles with a little bit of work.

**Here is your graph $A$ starting from a $C_8$**. The two bottom vertices colored in green are the ones with eccentricity $3$. The red ones have eccentricity $4$. 
[image: Graph A as described]

**Here is your graph $B$ starting from a $C_9$**. Colored similarly as above.
[image: Graph B as described]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the symmetry of C8->A I found an expansion for C9->B.
[image] : C8 -> A using symmetry

[image] : C9 -> B using symmetry and asymmetric ghost point

[image] : C9 -> B (choose A1 xor A2)

If You are not able to see the images clearly please forgive me. I did not have enough time to make a graphic. I can explain more later if necessary.